# how do I select and display records by userid?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a sales page where a user search and display records of his or her customers. And I have multiple users who are going to use this page. My problem is how do create the page in a way that when a user login it will only display the records of the user through his or her Userid.

I applied your example like this below:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        Session["UserId"] = User.Identity.Name;

        // using (var connection = new SqlConnection("mtbase"))
        {

            string value = null;
            if (HttpContext.Current.User != null)
            {
                value = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
            }
            else
            {
                value = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;
            }
            var split = value.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
            var UserId = split[split.Length - 1];
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM FixPrice WHERE UserId=@UserId", new SqlConnection("mtbase")))
            {
                // Add your parameter before opening the connection
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", UserId);
                // Open connection
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {

                }
                cmd.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My database table:

Table Name FixPrice

Id int  (PRIMARY KEY)

Date datatime

Admin nvarchar

Category nvarchar

Brand  varchar

Price  money

Qty  float

Sum  money

UserId  int (FOREIGN KEY)

Am still getting the same error:

Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.

Source Error:

Line 31:                 var split = value.Split(new char[] { '\' });
Line 32:                 var UserId = split[split.Length - 1];
Line 33:                 using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM FixPrice WHERE UserId=@UserId", new SqlConnection("Skyformatbase")))
Line 34:                 {
Line 35:                     // Add your parameter before opening the connection

Source File: c:\Users\migold\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\SKYAPP\DashBoard.aspx.cs    Line: 33

Comment: Can you please provide the steps you've taken thus far?

Comment: Once any user log into your application, you should save unique id of that specific user. 
Once user land on sales page you can use that unique id to display results for that specific user

Comment: Lookup the SQL/linq 'where' command

Answer (score 1):

Let's focus on this little bit first:

```
         var query = "SELECT * FROM FixPrice WHERE UserName @Username";
         using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
         {
            // Open connection
            connection.Open();
            // Add your parameter 
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", User.Identity.Name);
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
```

Your SQL needs to say `SELECT * FROM FixPrice WHERE UserName=@Username;`

You left off the **= (equals)** sign.

Next, you are reading in the User's **Name**, not the User's **Username**.

Then, of course, you are not closing your connection anywhere. It could be simplified with this form:

```
      string value = null;
      if (HttpContext.Current.User != null) {
        value = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
      } else {
        value = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;
      }
      var split = value.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
      var userName = split[split.Length - 1];
      using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM FixPrice WHERE UserName=@UserName", new SqlConnection("mtbase")))
      {
         // Add your parameter before opening the connection
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", userName);
         // Open connection
         cmd.Connection.Open();
         using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
            ...
         }
         cmd.Connection.Close();
      }
```

I hope this helps get you on track.

Answer (score -1):

You can put all the codes in the page_load event of that page.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
     //  Response.Write("<br>Page has been loaded first time.");
     //Read the user ID from session , asp.net membership or identity.
    // call database functions to read the record respect to that user and bind the 
list view , grid


    }
}
```